# Alternative to Stepper in WatchOS with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, watchos, stepper

G'Day All from Brisbane,

I have been starting to develop some trial watch apps and I came across something interesting and a bit odd. The SwiftUI Stepper is not available in WatchOS. This meant I had to modify my app code from the iOS version and now it uses the Digital Crown instead. That’s a bit annoying as the crown is not integer which means extra code to convert stuff. I cannot find any comments about the Stepper not being in watchOS in the internet which was a surprise. . Anyone got a better solution ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stepper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stepper) is now available as of watchOS 9

Comment: Cool, now I can revert back to a more universal code base, one little integer at a time.